# C# list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: c#

I have a list of lists of dictionaries. How do I add a dictionary to this data structure?

```
public class Messages
{
    public List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> store = new List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();

...
...
...

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("ID", "12345");
    dict.Add("Comment", "Hello");
   
int Count = 0;

messages.store[Count].Add(dict); // ???
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) When you say something _doesn't work_, you must also provide errors you encounter. What happens? Does it not compile? Does it throw a runtime error? Does it cause your computer to explode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is presumably that `messages.store` doesn't contain `Count + 1` elements for you to be able to access `messages.store[Count]`. You need to first make sure that element exists.

```
int Count = 0;
while (messages.store.Count <= Count) {
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> emptyListOfDict = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    messages.store.Add(emptyListOfDict);
}
messages.store[Count].Add(dict);
```

It probably makes more sense to include this as a method in the class instead of having external code to check it.

```
public class Messages {
    public List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> store = new List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();

    public void AddStore(int location, Dictionary<string, string> dict) {
        while (messages.store.Count <= Count) {
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> emptyListOfDict = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            this.store.Add(emptyListOfDict);
        }
        this.store[location].Add(dict);
    }
}

...

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("ID", "12345");
dict.Add("Comment", "Hello");

messages.AddStore(0, dict);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy answer! I wasn't exactly sure how to phrase the question but you got what I was trying to accomplish!